# Get executable query from postgres log

Tags: sql, logging, postgresql-9.2

I activated the logging of SQL statements in PostgreSQL version 9.2.
It started writing log statements like this:

> LOG:  execute : UPDATE qrz_TRIGGERS SET JOB_NAME = $1,
> JOB_GROUP = $2, IS_VOLATILE = $3, DESCRIPTION = $4, NEXT_FIRE_TIME =
> $5, PREV_FIRE_TIME = $6, TRIGGER_STATE = $7, TRIGGER_TYPE
> = $8, START_TIME = $9, END_TIME = $10, CALENDAR_NAME = $11, MISFIRE_INSTR = $12, PRIORITY = **$13** WHERE TRIGGER_NAME = $14 AND
> TRIGGER_GROUP = $15
>
> DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'dssSchedulerJob', $2 = 'DEFAULT', $3 = 'f', $4 > = NULL, $5 = '1501855865730', $6 = '1501855855730', $7 =
> 'BLOCKED', $8 = 'SIMPLE', $9 = '1252939835730', $10 = '0', $ 11 =
> NULL, $12 = '0', $13 = **'5'**, $14 = 'dssTrigger', $15 = 'DEFAULT'

I would like to take this SQL and run in with analysis inside pgAdmin3 for example.

Does somebody know how to enable Postgres to differentiate between integers and strings. Or better between parameters that need quotes and those who don't.

It's very messy to take the parameters and put them to the right place in the SQL. Also writing a simple tool to help here is impossible or very difficult because it does not know if quotes are needed or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see all values but null here are in single quotes. you can pass them to prepared statement as they are provided here. A short example:

```
t=# prepare a(int) as (select $1/2);
PREPARE
t=# execute a('4');
 ?column?
----------
        2
(1 row)

t=# execute a('32');
 ?column?
----------
       16
(1 row)
```

so you can use `LOG: execute` part as is to prepare statement and parse `DETAIL: parameters:` to use as arguments for the statement

Comment: That means I can use the values with quotes, doesn't matter if they are strings or int values?

Comment: there's a "default cast" of integer as text to integer, so it won't allow `'99a'` to be passed as integer, but `'99'` will allow.